# Angular ng serve development server not accessible any more in local network, after upgrading to MacOS Catalina

Tags: angular, localhost, macos-catalina

I never had issues in serving my local development on Angular 8 projects to my local network by using the IP of the development machine. E.g. using ng serve --host 192.168.1.3 and then access the app by this URL in my local network: https://192.168.1.3:4200/ 
After upgrading to MacOS Catalina, this is not working any more. Unfortunately I did not find anything about the issue discussed in the dev community, would be great to find some tips here :-)

Comment: has you any firewall? In windows you need "open the port" (create a rule in the firewall)

Comment: firewall is turned of on my Mac